# Textbook covering calculus and probability theory

Tags: reference-request, mathematical-economics

Is anyone able to recommend a textbook that covers the following topics at a level suitable for econ undergraduates?

- Differential calculus, including the various rules of differentiation and partial derivatives.
- At least some integral calculus.
- Probability theory, expected values, Bayes' rule.
- (optional) basic set theory.

I can find books with a nice treatment of calculus, but am struggling to find a book that also includes coverage of topics in probability.

Failing one book that covers all of these topics, I also welcome suggestions of books that might work well together to give such coverage.

Comment: Just wondering, why don't you just want two books?

Comment: @wythagoras Well, if it has to be two books then I would use two books (in which  case I would appreciate a recommendation of a good book for basic probability theory that doesn't get too sidetracked into topics in empirical estimation etc.). But mostly, I would prefer one book because my experience is that students find it more convenient if there's a single source for them to consult.

Comment: In a [course](http://www.studiegids.science.ru.nl/2015/en/course/36996/) similiar to yours at the Radboud University, the Netherlands, they use two different lecture notes and each set of notes recommends a book.

Comment: @wythagoras Thanks! Would you mind posting that as an answer so that it can be up-voted (and potentially accepted). That way the best answer will be more visible to others who end up here with a similar question.

Comment: I did not post it as an answer because I do not really believe it answers the question. However, I'm happy to post of course.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a [course](http://www.studiegids.science.ru.nl/2015/en/course/36996/) similiar to yours at the Radboud University Nijmegen, the Netherlands, they use two different lecture notes (in Dutch) and each set of notes recommends a book.

For probability theory, they recommend the following book:

- Murray R. Spiegel, John J. Schiller, R. A. Srinivasan: (Schaum’s Outline of Theory and Problems of) Probability and Statistics. McGraw-Hill
  Companies, 2000, 408 p., ISBN: 0071350047.